# Get data from curl to put in array and display in php

Tags: php, curl

I need to get the data from a curl in php and have it display all data in that array. I can't seem to get it to work at all. I am trying a while statement but that does not seem to work. It's like it's not an array. I only need to pull out the zip_code for each place and display that zip code.

Here is my code:

```
function remote_get_contents($url)
{
    if (function_exists('curl_get_contents') AND 
 function_exists('curl_init'))
    {
            return curl_get_contents($url);
    }
    else
    {
            return file_get_contents($url);
    }
}

function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = 'URL_HIDDEN';
$object = json_decode(remote_get_contents($url));
$url2 = 'URL_HIDDEN';
$object2    = json_decode(remote_get_contents($url2));

$zip = $object->postal;
$city = $object->city;
$zips = $object2->zip_code;

echo $city ." | ". $zip . " | ". $zips ."<br />";
```

Here is the raw data output (all I need is each zip_code to show) It could be longer or shorter. In some cases it could be 50+ zip codes that need to be pulled out. Other cases it could just be 1 or 2.

```
 {
  "zip_codes": [
    {
        "zip_code": "27356",
        "distance": 47.395,
        "city": "Star",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27247",
        "distance": 46.972,
        "city": "Ether",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27325",
        "distance": 45.174,
        "city": "Robbins",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27259",
        "distance": 44.428,
        "city": "Highfalls",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27330",
        "distance": 49.074,
        "city": "Sanford",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27341",
        "distance": 40.783,
        "city": "Seagrove",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27237",
        "distance": 46.55,
        "city": "Cumnock",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "28137",
        "distance": 49.68,
        "city": "Richfield",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27208",
        "distance": 38.639,
        "city": "Bennett",
        "state": "NC"
    },
    {
        "zip_code": "27252",
        "distance": 41.732,
        "city": "Goldston",
        "state": "NC"
    }
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the multidimensional data.  Something like this...

```
foreach (json_decode(remote_get_contents($url2))->zip_codes as $row) {
    echo $row->city ." | ". $row->zip_code . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with that

```
$object2    = json_decode(remote_get_contents($url2), true);
```

adding will convert the json to an associated array
[json_decode doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: You might want to add that he then needs to iterate over the array. I get the impression from his question that he doesn't understand that aspect.

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted?  Changing from object to array will fix nothing.